# Pulley with mass and string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, rigid-body-dynamics

I am dealing with dynamics of a rigid body, and I can't understand the "algorithm"/problem solving approach behind solving to set equations to solve problems: I thought it was to apply ${F}_{total}=ma$ for each body and then ${M}_{total}=\frac{dL_{tot}}{dt}$ where $L_{tot}$ is the total angolar momentum and ${M}_{total}$ the sum of all external torques (obviously this is oversimplified and you have to do the proper considerations if there are tensions etc).

This exercise though, gave me particular problems.

**EXERCISE**

A body of mass $m_1$ is lifted by a force $F$ on an ideal string that passes on a pulley of mass $m_3$, like below:

[image]

The pulley is a circle with radius $R$, moment of inertia $I=\frac{1}{2}m_3R^2$ and no friction. The string doesn't slide on the pulley, has no mass and isn't elastic (ideal, as said above). Find the acceleration $a$ of the mass.

**SOLUTION**

My professor solved it by saying that

$M_{total}=M_F+M_{F_{g_1}}=RF-m_1gR$ (where $F_{g_1}=m_1g$ is the gravity of the mass)

$L_{total}=Rm_1v+I\omega$ (where $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the pulley and $v$ the tangenzial velocity of the mass)

and substituting these two in ${M}_{total}=\frac{dL_{tot}}{dt}$

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. Why isn't he considering tensions but forces directly, if both the forces ($F$ and $F_g$) are applied through the string? Is this a "shortcut" that we can take if we see something in the problem?
2. If we consider tensions, what should we do?

**ATTEMPT TO SOLVE CONSIDERING TENSIONS**

The tensions are different on the two sides of the pulley (say $T_1$ the one near the mass and $T_2$ the one near the force), so how do you write equations of forces if there are two different tensions on a string with no mass? The only thing that I can think of that makes sense is applying the 2nd newton law on the mass, thus getting $F_{g_1}-T_1=m_1a$ (with $a$ that is also the acceleration of the whole system).
Then we can get the torque of $T_1$ and of $T_2$, so:
$M_{tot}=M_{T_1}+M_{T_2}=RT_1+RT_2$

Then, we obtaining $L_{total}=Rm_1v+I\omega$ and substitute in ${M}_{total}=\frac{dL_{tot}}{dt}$, but we still have to find $T_2$.

- With another mass $m_3$ instead of a force everything seems simpler, since we can apply the 2nd newton law to the mass and get $T_2-F_{g_2}=m_2a$. Is this true?

**NOTE**

Note that in point 2) I'm asking a way of reasoning that I can apply to other problems (I - maybe wrongly - thought that the general case was to consider both forces and torques, and also tensions), not just a physical intuition about this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the instructor is wrong.  The tension force in the bottom part of the rope is necessarily *larger* than $mg$, because otherwise, the net force on the block would be zero, and it wouldn't accelerate. So:

> 1. Why isn't he considering tensions but forces directly, if both the forces (F and Fg) are applied through the string? Is this a "shortcut" that we can take if we see something in the problem?

The answer is no.  You cannot take this shortcut (it's wrong), and it's not a good idea to take shortcuts like this in general.  People usually guess the wrong thing (e.g., the normal force exerted upward on an object is not always $mg$ in magnitude, and the tension force holding up a block of mass $m$ is not always $mg$, etc.), and apparently the instructor did that (or, alternatively, you have misread the solution, or the instructor implicitly assumed that the acceleration is *zero*, which would make the tension in the *entire* rope equal to $mg$).

> 2. If we consider tensions, what should we do?

You should do exactly what you started the post out by saying: write down Newton's 2nd law for each object.  More specifically, draw free-body diagrams for each object (*extended* free-body diagrams for objects that can rotate, showing *where* the forces act), write down Newton's 2nd Law for each interacting object, determine any constraints (e.g., Newton's 3rd Law force-pairs, equal tension forces due to the model for a massless inextensible string, equal accelerations because two objects are tied together, etc.), plug in known model forces (e.g., gravity, kinetic friction), and solve for the quantities you don't know (e.g., tension, normal forces, static friction force, accelerations, etc.).

---

For completeness, here's the full solution. There are two tension forces in the string, one for the hanging part and one for the horizontal part, because the rope is not sliding along the pulley but turning it.  The net torque (about the center of mass, with positive clockwise rotation sense) on the pulley is
$$
\tau_{\textrm{net}} = \tau_{\textrm{hor. rope}} + \tau_{\textrm{ver. rope}}
= T_{\textrm{hor}}R - T_{\textrm{ver}}R\,
$$
leading to the rotational form of the second law, given by
$$
I \alpha = \tau_{\textrm{net}} = T_{\textrm{hor}}R - T_{\textrm{ver}}R\,.
$$
For the hanging mass, Newton's 2nd law takes the form
$$
ma = T_{\textrm{ver}}-mg\,,
$$
with up being the positive direction.  This is now two equations with four unknowns ($a$, $\alpha$, and the two tensions).  There is a relationship between $a$ and $\alpha$ due to the rope not slipping along the cylinder, and the tension force $T_{\textrm{hor}}$ in the horizontal part of the rope is just $F_0$, using Newton's 3rd Law.

Answer (score 1):

> so how do you write equations of forces if there are two different tensions on a string with no mass?

Don't consider it a single string.  Consider it to be two different strings.  One from pulley to the force, one from the pulley to the mass.

Each (separate) string in this consideration will have some set of forces on it that sum to zero, and that will develop a tension within the string.

The masses and the pulley can have unequal forces and accelerate, but the string segments cannot.

---

A "light" string has minimal mass and therefore responds instantly to any change of forces, so that forces on both ends (and the tension throughout) have identical magnitudes.

If the pulley were also "light", it would be able to spin at any speed in response to any torque.  If the two segments of the string had different tensions, the pulley would move instantly until the tensions were identical.  So such a pulley would only serve to change the direction of the forces that the string was able to impart.

But the pulley here has a moment of inertia and friction with the string.  This enables it to create a force along the string.  Now the tension in each segment may be different.

Conceptually, I like to think of it as 2 strings, each of which is placing a tangential force/torque on the pulley.  You can then equate the magnitude of the forces on each end.

But you can also think of it as the tangential force from the pulley is creating the difference in tensions between the segments.
$$T_2 - T_1 = F_{\rm{pulley->string}}$$

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that, but I don’t know how to justify it, and I didn’t know how to «unify» the fact that it seems (from a force point of view) that we have to different strings, but they have to move at the same speed/they have the same acceleration. Can I ask you if there is a reason to that? What is the role of the pulley?

Comment: Thanks your explanations are really clear. If I understood right, the force of the pulley on the string is entirely caused by the friction between the pulley and the string, because that is (obviously) what causes the string to rotate the pulley instead of sliding along. But how is it possible, then, that a lot of these exercises with the pulley say to not consider friction, and in writing the equations to solve the problem we don’t do it either (see @march answer)? It has to “cancel out”  somewhere I guess? Where is the application point of the friction force, in case?

Comment: If the pulley is *also* "light", then the system behaves the same whether the string slides or spins the pulley.  That is common in many physics problems.  In this particular question, the pulley is not light and has a specific moment of inertia.   This pulley must be connected to the string (via friction) for that to matter.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it’s like it’s useful to consider the pulley and the string  as a single object together as a whole, from when the string touches the pulley to when it leaves it, correct?

Comment: Yes.  Or that the string on that section just doesn't exist.   Either is equivalent.